# Scrapy - how to join data together from different parts of a website

Tags: python, meta, scrapy

I am in the process of building a crawler. Now, I want it to navigate all available pages on the site, and [i] fill a number of data fields for each product, and [ii], for each product, drill into the corresponding product url, and populate a number of other data fields. I want all of the data in the same {} for each product. But instead, what the crawler is doing is carrying out [i], and then [ii], so that part [ii] is populated in a separate {}.

I want to somehow add data [i] into [ii]. `request.meta['item'] = item` looks to be something which could work, but I have not yet succeeded in getting it to work.

I have the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from maxine.items import CrawlerItem



class Crawler1Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler1"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'starturl.com',
    )


rules = [
    #visit each page
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="listnavpagenum"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    #click on each product link
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="exhib_status exhib_status_interiors"]')), callback='parse_detail', follow=True),
    ]


def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    elements = sel.xpath('//div[@class="ez_listitem_wrapper"]')
    items = []
    results = []
    n = 0
    for element in elements:
        item = CrawlerItem()
        n = n + 1
        #work out how to put images into image folder
        item['title'] = element.css('a.exhib_status.exhib_status_interiors').xpath('text()').extract_first()
        item['title_code'] = element.xpath('.//div[@class="ez_merge8"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['item_url'] = element.xpath('//div[@class="ez_merge4"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        item['count'] = n
        yield item

        #items.append(item)
    #return items



def parse_detail(self, response):
    item = CrawlerItem()
    item['telephone'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="ez_entry_contactinfo"]//text()').re('[0-9]{4,}\s*[0-9]{4,}')
    item['website'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="ez_entry_contactinfo"]//text()').re('(?:http://)?www.[a-z0-9\/?_\- ]+.[0-9a-z]+')
    yield item
```

Suggestion as to how I can get all the data into one {} for each product would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: 20/11/15

I have amended the code as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from maxine.items import CrawlItem



class Crawler1Spider(CrawlSpider):
name = "test"
allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
start_urls = (
    'starturl.com',
)

rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="listnavpagenum"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        ]


def parse_item(self, response):

    item = CrawlItem()
    sel = Selector(response)
    elements = sel.xpath('//div[@class="ez_listitem_wrapper"]')
    items = []
    n = 0
    for element in elements:
        n = n + 1
        #work out how to put images into image folder
        #item['image_urls'] = selector.xpath('//a[@class="exhib_status exhib_status_interiors"]/img/@src').extract()
        item['title'] = element.css('a.exhib_status.exhib_status_interiors').xpath('text()').extract_first()
        item['title_code'] = element.xpath('.//div[@class="ez_merge8"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['item_url'] = element.xpath('//div[@class="ez_merge4"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        item['count'] = n
        item_detail_url = item['item_url'] = element.xpath('//div[@class="ez_merge4"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        # crawl the item and pass the item to the following request with *meta*
    yield Request(url=item_detail_url, callback=self.parse_detail,meta=dict(item=item))


def parse_detail(self, response):
    #get the item from the previous passed meta
    item = response.meta['item']
    # keep populating the item
    item['telephone'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="ez_entry_contactinfo"]//text()').re('[0-9]{4,}\s*[0-9]{4,}')
    item['website'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="ez_entry_contactinfo"]//text()').re('(?:http://)?www.[a-z0-9\/?_\- ]+.[0-9a-z]+')
    yield item
```

I'm getting the data in the same {}'s, however, the robot is only extracting data from the last item per page. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't use `rules` for this case, as every request is independent when they reach the site you want to crawl.

You'll need to define your own behaviour from `start_requests`:

```
def start_requests(self):
     yield Request(url=myinitialurl, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
     # crawl the initial page and then do something with that info
     yield Request(url=producturl, callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
     item = CrawlerItem()
     # crawl the item and pass the item to the following request with *meta*
     yield Request(url=item_detail_url, callback=self.parse_detail, meta=dict(item=item))

def parse_detail(self, response):
     # get the item from the previous passed meta
     item = response.meta['item']
     # keep populating the item
     yield item
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, the crawler is only scraping data for the last product on each page. I want it to [i] crawl an item on a page, extracting data, [ii] visit item url, and extract data on that page, [iii] repeat steps [i]-[ii] for next product, [iv] go to next page, repeat steps [i] to [iv].

Comment: Your `yield` statement isn't part of the `for` loop. Indent it one more level and it will be executed every loop instead of just once after the loop has ended.

Answer (score 0):

try instantiating `item = CrawlItem()` within the for loop in `parse_item`.